# Why do I have to assign a dummy value to a variable when using 'while' clause in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I am new to python so while learning the 'while loops' in python i came across the following  code

```
word = 'dummy'
while word:
    word = raw_input('Please enter a word: ')
    print 'The word was '+ word
```

so my question is why do we have to assign a dummy value that is a a unused value to the variable here there is no explanation for this in the book ... please help

Thanks

Akash

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "dummy" value. `while` loops work in this way, that they verify their conditions *before* each iteration, including the first iteration. Consider this:

```
value = False
while value:
    print "This will not be printed"
```

- in this case, the loop won't be run even once.

`while [X]` means literally: "run loop/continue iterations as long as whatever `[X]` is, evaluates to `True`". So in case of `while value` it's "run as long as `value` evaluates to `True`".

Beside that, if you won't define the variable it is ... undefined :) in the line `while word:`. Interpreter won't know what to verify if `word` hasn't been defined before.

Your case can be generalized as follows:

```
loopCondition = True
while loopCondition:
    word = raw_input('Please enter a word: ')
    print 'The word was ' + word
    loopCondition = len(word) > 0
```

The last statement can be of course just `loopCondition = word` because empty string evaluates to `False`, and non-empty string evaluates to `True` - but it shows the intent clearly in this example.

Comment: Even better: `loopCondition = bool(word)`. It states intention more explicitly.

Comment: can you explain what exactly the line 'while variable: ' means i think i am getting confused there

Comment: @Programmer This is explained in every good Python tutorial - I recommend you find some and read them :) I've added a simple explanation to the answer.

Comment: am i interpreting it correctly that basically the line 'while variable: ' is another way to write 'while true: ' or while false: ' but we assign the value true or false to another variable so that we can use it in the loop

Comment: am i interpreting it correctly that basically the line 'while variable: ' is another way to write 'while true: ' or while false: ' but we assign the value true or false to another variable so that we can use it in the loop

Comment: @Programmer Yes, you can look at it this way.